# Alexa Presentation Language Document rendering while speaking

Tags: command, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

I am trying to render an Alexa Presentation Language document while Alexa is speaking her speech. I tried with a pager with several pages and the AutoPager command. The problem I am trying to solve is that the document is rendered when Alexa starts speaking but the command is started when the speech is finished, and I would like to see the three pages moving while speaking. 
I am using the RenderDocumet and the executeCommand and the speak directives of responseBuilder.

The Document Template:
PagerDoc —>

```
{
    "type": "APL",
    "version": "1.0",
    "theme": "dark",
    "import": [],
    "resources": [],
    "styles": {},
    "layouts": {},
    "mainTemplate": {
        "parameters": [
            "datasource"
        ],
        "item": [{

                "type": "Container",
                "items": [
                    {
                    "type": "Sequence",
                    "id": "pagerComponentId",
                    "scrollDirection": "vertical",
                    "numbered": true,
                    "width": "100vw",
                    "height": "100vh",
                    "alignItems": "center",
                    "justifyContent": "center",
                    "direction": "column",
                    "items": [

                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "source": "${datasource.app.properties.images.robot1}",
                            "position": "relative",
                            "width": "100vw",
                            "height": "100vh"

                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "source": "${datasource.app.properties.images.robot2}",
                            "position": "relative",
                            "width": "100vw",
                            "height": "100vh"

                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]

            }
        ]      
        }

    }
```

And the Directives:

```
var response = handlerInput.responseBuilder;
                return response
.addDirective({
                    type : 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.RenderDocument',
                    token: 'pagerToken',
                    document : pagerDoc,
                    datasources : {
                        "app": {
                            "properties": {
                                "images": {
                                    "robot1": "https://xxx/robot1.png",
                                    "robot2": "https://xxx/robot2.png"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
               .addDirective({
                    type: 'Alexa.Presentation.APL.ExecuteCommands',
                    token: 'pagerToken',
                    commands: [
                       {
                            "type": "Parallel",
                            "commands": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Scroll",
                                    "componentId": "pagerComponentId",
                                    "distance": 1


          }
                                ]
                              })
                           .speak(speechOutput)
                          .reprompt(repromptOutput)
                          .getResponse();
```

Could somebody tell me what should I do? If this is possible with Alexa?
Thanks a lot in advance and best regards,
Fernando

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The [tag:APL] tag refers to [a programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) unrelated to Alexa.

Comment: nope, it is Alexa Presentation Language (APL)

Comment: No. The "APL" tag, *on stackoverflow*, refers to a programming language. The tag for the alexa presentation language is... "alexa-presentation-language".

Answer (score 0):

It's not posible yet. If you wait until the release of APL 1.1 (coming soon) 
APL 1.1 will add `onMount` to the APL document which should allow for the execution of commands as soon as a document is loaded (eg. before alexa speaks)

Comment: Is there a way to do this other than `onMount`?  I would like to execute commands without using the `RenderDocument` directive again.

Comment: I lost track of APL versions, not on Alexa currently. You should go and check the docs of the latest APL version. Sorry